# How to implement redis cache in node.js project in Windows

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, node-redis, redis-cache

I have implemented redis cache for get method, but if Redis server is closed, my node.js project doesn't start again. If the Redis server is running everything runs fine. What should I do?

I get this error when I start my project without Redis server:

```
PS D:\MyWorkSpace\PAS DEV BRANCH\cs_app_api> npm run dev

> dev
> ts-node ./src/server.ts

App running on the port 8081
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
PS D:\MyWorkSpace\PAS DEV BRANCH\cs_app_api>
```